# excel append text to column with condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

if have two column A and B. What I want is if when in B string not equal to 'Sr' or 'Jr' I will have to append it to A. I have my code here but error found.

```
=if(or(B214 !='Jr', B214 != 'Sr'),A214&" "&B214))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=IF(OR(B1="Sr",B1="Jr"),"",CONCATENATE(A1,"  ",B1))

Example:

[image]

// I'hve assumed that if the B string is equal to either Jr or Sr then leave it as Blank. If you want any other value to be populated if B is equal to Sr or Jr replace "" in second argument of IF by the desired cell name

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
=if(or(B214 ="Jr", B214 = "Sr"), A214 , A214 & " " & B214)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is misleading. It does not append text to column A, it concatenates A and B in a new column C.